# julia counterpart for "from module import some_func" in python

Tags: julia

I find `using Module` in julia is equivalent to `from Module import *` in python. Is there any way to import a single function or variable from a module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import e.g. a single function with

```
using Module.func
```

If you also want to be able to extend the function with new methods, use instead

```
import Module.func
```

If you want to import several named functions and variables from the same module, you can e.g. use one of

```
using Module: func1, func2
import Module: func1, func2
```

All of these forms allow to import definitions from `Module` regardless of whether they are exported there, unlike `using Module`, which only imports exported definitions.

Also keep in mind that it is really values that are imported, not variables, so if you try to assign to an imported variable, you will not see a change in the originating module (and you will get a warning).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a module `Foo` with a function `bar` (or something else specific you wan to import) you can do:

```
import Foo: bar
```

This brings only `bar` into scope.